# Simple stack and linked list

Tags: python, linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel

I know that Python has a built-in `list` data structure, but I want to implement my own linked list and stack data structures for practice.

I have three classes `Node`, `Stack` and `List`.

The code works, but I feel there is a better way to do this.

I would like to have some general critique.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.item = None
        self.link = None


class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.top = 0
        self.head = Node()

    def isEmpty(self):
        return top == 0

    def push(self, item):
        oldHead = self.head
        self.head = Node()
        self.head.item = item
        self.head.link = oldHead
        self.top += 1


    def pop(self):
        item = self.head.item
        self.head = self.head.link
        self.top -= 1
        return item

class List:
    def __init__(self):
        self.top = 0
        self.head = Node()

    def get(self, *args):
        if not args:
            return self.head.item
        elif type(args[0]) is int:
            pos = args[0]
            current = self.head
            count = 0
            while count < pos - 1 and current.link != None:
                current = current.link
                count += 1
           return current.item
       else:  
            raise TypeError

    def pop(self, *args):
        if not args:
            item = self.head.item
            head = self.head.link
            return item

    def append(self, item):
        oldhead = self.head
        self.head = Node()
        self.head.item = item
        self.head.link = oldhead
        self.top += 1

    def insert(self, item, pos):
        current = self.head
        count = 0
        while count < pos - 1 and current.link != None:
            current = current.link
            count += 1
        node = Node()
        node.item = item

        node.link = current.link
        current.link = node
        self.top += 1
```

Comment: It’s more idiomatic to use `if x is (not) None` rather than the Boolean operators `==` and `!=`.

Comment: Okay, makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little hard to review code like this in Python because we're pretending there's no built-in list class, but a Python without a list doesn't feel like Python at all, so the code ends up looking like some other language.

I mention this because there are named tuples in Python 2.7 and Python 3, and they pretty much do exactly what your `Node` class does:

```
import collections
Node = collections.namedtuple('Node', ['item', 'link'])

n = Node(item=22, link=self.head)  # Make a new node.
```

Then again, if we're pretending lists don't exist, maybe we should pretend tuples don't exist either.

---

There's a lot of duplication in your code. These two classes are very similar. The `push` and `append` methods appear to be exactly the same method, for example. The two `pop` methods are almost exactly the same. The constructors are the same. So this seems like a good place to use inheritance. Make a base class, maybe with a name like `LinkedList`, which has the constructor and any methods which are exactly the same. Make the `List` and `Stack` both inherit from the `LinkedList`.

In your current code, you have separate implementations for `pop` that seem to do exactly the same thing, except that the stack version also removes the item. I would add separate `pop` and `top` methods. `pop` always removes and returns the top item, while `top` just returns the item without removing it. Then, if you want to make it impossible to remove the top item of a list, override the `pop` method to just call `top`. This is more or less how C++'s STL works, although C++'s `pop` doesn't return the item it removed.

So the final code would look something like this:

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.top_index = 0
        self.head = Node()

    def push(self, item):
        # Code from push / append here

    def pop(self):
        # Code that removes and returns the top here.

    def top(self):
        # Code that just returns the head here.

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.top_index == 0

class List(LinkedList):
    def insert(self, item, pos=0):
        # Code for insert here.

class Stack(LinkedList):
    # Whatever functionality is unique to the stack.
    # If there isn't any, you can consider not having a stack
    # class and just using a LinkedList.
```

I'll leave the details up to you, but that's basically how I would do it.

---

Am I right in thinking the following function is incomplete?

```
def pop(self, *args):
    if not args:
        item = self.head.item
        head = self.head.link
        return item
```

Were you going to add an `else` clause the retrieves the item at a specified index, like what you have in `get`? If that was what you had in mind, I think default arguments would be a better solution than using `*args`. Using `get` as a model, something like this:

```
def get(self, pos=0):
    if pos == 0:
        return self.head.item
    elif pos > 0:
        current = self.head
        count = 0
        while count < pos - 1 and current.link != None:
            current = current.link
            count += 1
       return current.item
    else:
       raise IndexError()
```

I find this clearer than the version with `*args`. Also, in case you wanted to use `*args` in the future, you can now do so without having to parse it.

---

Your use of style conventions and code formatting looks good. It can be confusing to get this right in Python since the standard library sets such a horrible example :)

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a detailed response. I have only skimmed through it but there is so much for me to learn here. Thank you so much!

Comment: And yes, the `pop` method is incomplete. I really need to look more into default arguments.

Comment: @Bhargav You're welcome, glad I could help. Default arguments are one of my favorite features of Python, and one of the few things from C++ that I miss when I'm using Java :)